# how to use shell to count Chinese characters in file encoded in UTF-8

Tags: shell, utf-8, wc

> **cat doc.txt** and the following characters will show:

```
你好 Hello!
这是中文。This is a Chinese doc.
```

I can use the command

> wc -w doc.txt

but it will show:

```
8 doc.txt
```

this command take characters **你好** and **这是中文** both as a single word, while in fact **你好** are two Chinese words and **这是中文** four.

What I want is to get these Chinese words counting right(there are 12 words in the example), could anyone help out?

Comment: try adding `LANG=?chinese? wc -c file` (not sure of the proper value to use after LANG, you should be able to find it without  much searching. Also, if you're using a hertiage Unix (AIX, HP, less so Solaris), don't count on this working regardless what you do. Maybe the latest Linux with up-to-date `wc`. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `-m` or `--chars` option:

```
$ echo -n "你好" | wc -m
```

**Output:**

```
2
```